# finding the avg number of comparisons of random permutation arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I have to write  a function in cpp, which runs N **random permutation** arrays with the size M, and returns the **avg number of comparisons** of finding the min and max elements of these arrays. 
I guess I should use an algorithm like that, to find the min and max for each array:

```
MaxMin(A)
Max=Min=A[1]
for i <-1 to Length(A)
    if A[i] < Min
        Min <- A[i]
    else if A[i] > Max
        Max <- A[i]
```

**But what is the way of generating random permuation array with a certain size?**
(I know how to generate a random array)

I also would like to ask what the difference between finding the avg number of comparisons of finding the min and max of "usual" random arrays, between the ovg number in a case of permutation random arrays. **Do you suppose to get a different number of comparisons?**

Comment: [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) can help you with generation random permutations.

Comment: Comparisons to find min/max is always size - 1. You have to compare every element except the first to the greatest element you have currently seen. No need for some program to generate random arrays and stuff.

Comment: You're way overthinking this problem, just like you did with finding the two greatest values. If you're in a class, talk to your instructor about it.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm to find the minimum element of an array might look like this:

```
int min = array[0];
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if(array[i] < min) //Note that this is a comparison no matter if min
    {                  //needs to be updated or not
        min = array[i];
    }
}
```

This code uses `min` to store the current smallest element we have seen, **compares each element except the first one to it**, and updates `min` if necessary.

Notice that a comparison happens every iteration, which is always exactly `size - 1` times.

Still not convinced? Write a short function to do the comparison and increment a global counter, using it in the loop in place of the `<` operator:

```
int counter = 0;
bool isless(int a, int b) { counter++; return a < b; }
int min = array[0];
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if(isless(array[i], min))
    {
        min = array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: May you consider  the matter of permutation?

Comment: @NOA It's the same no matter what is in the array unless the algorithm already knows information about the array. For example, the algorithm might be specifically designed to work on arrays containing permutations of consecutive integers. Also, note that this is only true if you're only finding the min or max in the array. If you're finding the min and the max at the same time, there are ways you can get away with fewer comparisons than 2(size - 1), although the runtime would still be O(n).